# Found nil when accessing an outlet

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, iboutlet

I have created a `containerView` in storyboard, I did cntrl drag to his viewcontroller and created an IBOutlet.

When trying to access this outlet I get an error

> found nil while unwrapping.

```
class NavigationController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        controller1  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

        controller1.delegate=self

        self.containerView.addSubview(controller1.view)
    }
}
```

I can confirm that its connected because I see the outlet's dot, and when touch it on editor it blinks on storyboard.

Have tried clean, remove, and anything else.

Tried to load in   `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` will get same results.

Comment: How do you create your controller?

Comment: which one? the one who holds the container? its the first view to appear in storyboard ( has the initial view controller arrow)

Comment: And `containerView`is a subview of `self.view`or is it a top-level object? BTW: You needn't load `Main.storyboard`. You might simply use `self.storyboard`.

Comment: Did you checked or it is solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

My Outlet :

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
```

My StoryBoard: - VC With ContainerView

[image]

StoryBoard : - VC to be added in ContainerView

[image]

Create a Object for ViewController to be added

```
private lazy var FirstObject: VC1 =
    {
        // Instantiate View Controller
        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as! VC1
        
        // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
        self.addChildViewController(viewController)
        return viewController
    }()
```

Create function that will Add your VC object in Container View

```
private func add1(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController)
    {
        // Configure Child View
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.size.width, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height)
        
        // Add Child View Controller
        addChildViewController(viewController)
        viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        
        // Add Child View as Subview
        containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
        
        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

Now in DidLoad Just Simply call

```
self.add1(asChildViewController: FirstObject)
```

Output :

[image]

**Also Check for Second option that you can give a try with**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274222/6080920

No need to use Container View Specially for this purpose just a Normal UIView can also be used check link for this

**Sample Project using UIView**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M12Nv4PLNUePSJFHf7w8b08M2_mWcUEC

**Sample Project using ContainerView**

https://github.com/iOS-Geek/ContainerViews.git

Comment: You didn't even use your container, this will not answer my question

Comment: Updated Answer used two container Views check at - https://github.com/iOS-Geek/ContainerViews.git